# PowerShell - Cannot uninstall the Microsoft.HEIFImageExtension on several Win10 systems

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell, package-management

I have a PowerShell command line to uninstall the HEIF image extension component provided by default on Win10/Win11 OS. This command is the following:

> get-appxpackage Microsoft.HEIFImageExtension -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers

On all systems I run this command from a PowerShell instance opened as administrator.

Normally this command works as expected on most of the systems on which I execute it. But on some Windows 10 system, it fails with the following error:

> Remove-AppxPackage : Removal failed. Please contact your software vendor.
> Deployment Remove operation with target volume C: on Package
> Microsoft.HEIFImageExtension_1.0.62561.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe from:   failed with error 0x80070002. See
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app deployment issues.
> At line:1 char:58
>
> - ... Microsoft.HEIFImageExtension -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
>
> ---
>
> - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Remove-AppxPackage], COMException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.RemoveAppxPackageCommand

The systems on which this command fails are always Windows 10 OSes, I never faced a such case on a Win11 system. I run it from an admin account, and only one account exists on the target OS.

I cannot figure out why this command fails only on these conditions. Has someone already faced a such issue? How may I resolve it?

Comment: According to the link in the error, that code means "File Not Found". Maybe it got partially uninstalled already? Depending on the win10 build, you might be able to run `Get-AppxPackage [...] | Reset-AppxPackage` then uninstall it. Or option 3 here if you don't have `Reset-AppxPackage` (basically just re-register using manifest): https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/165667-how-reset-settings-app-windows-10-a.html#option3

Comment: Try `Get-AppxPackage *HEIFImageExtension* -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers`.

Comment: @Jean-MilostReymond.... On the problem systems, see if all users are logged off and no disconnected sessions exist if it works then. See if going to `sysdm.cpl` | `Advanced` | `User Profiles` | `Settings`, if removing any "unknown" accounts, rebooting, then rerunning the command if that resolves it.